# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1}(y^2+y)\sqrt{1+(2y+1)^2}dy$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve this integral and I can't figure out how to do it using the basic methods. Can someone help out?

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int(y^2+y)\sqrt{1+(2y+1)^2}\,dy$$
Let
$$(2y+1)=\sinh(t) \implies y=\frac{1}{2} (\sinh (t)-1)\implies dy=\frac{1}{2}\cosh (t)$$ which make
$$I=\frac{1}{8} \int\left(\sinh ^2(t)-1\right) \cosh ^2(t)\,dt$$

Now, use the double angle formulae to face very simple things.

Comment: What about the bounds?

Comment: There are no limit so no bounds here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:let $f(y)=1+{(2y+1)}^2=4y^2+4y+2$

$f'(y)=8y+4$

Hence we write $$y^2+y=l(4y^2+4y+2)+m(8y+4)+n$$

Now find $l,m,n$ and integrate.....