# Compute the scalar line integral $\int_{C}^{}x^2+2y-zds$ where C is the line segment from (0,1,0) to (1,0,1).

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble with this question. I tried to make a relation between x, y, and z using the points given, and I came up with $x=z=-y+1$, which led to trying to solve the integral

$$\int_{0}^{1}(y^2+y)\sqrt{1+(2y+1)^2}dy$$

But I don't know if this is the right approach.

I was assisted in evaluating the integral, but I'm just not sure.

[How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1}(y^2+y)\sqrt{1+(2y+1)^2}dy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909285/how-to-integrate-int-01y2y-sqrt12y12dy/3909300#3909300)

Comment: Your integrand is not set up correctly. It is easier to just parametrize the curve which is straight line between given points.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is not the correct integral that you came up with. The formula you should be using is:

$$\int_C f(x,y,z) ds = \int_a^{b} f(x(t),y(t),z(t))\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 + z'(t)^2}dt$$

With the parametric representation of the line segment. You should get the parameterization as:

$$x = t, y = 1-t, z = t, 0\leq t \leq 1$$

Integral then becomes

$$\int_C (x^2 + 2y - z)ds = \int_0^{1} (t^2+2(1-t)-t)\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2+1^2}dt$$

$$=\sqrt{3}\int_0^{1} t^2 - 3t +2dt = \frac{5\sqrt{3}}{6}.$$

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain why leaving x and z in terms of y doesn't work?

Comment: It's because the formula for line integrals does not work with the symmetric equations of lines. In general, for any curve $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the best way to represent it will always be with a parameterization. There aren't "symmetric" forms of all curves, only lines. This is why they have trained you to always use parametrization with line integrals, cause they work for ALL curves with a parameterization. In reality, $x = z = 1-y$ is just another way of writing $x = t, y = 1-t, z = t$. In short: They are the exact same thing, but the formula we applied only works for parameterizations.

Comment: Also think about your usage of $ds$ and $dy$. Those are two totally different things. The reason this formula I used works is because we have rewritted $ds$ as $\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 + z'(t)^2}dt$. $ds$ doesn't just change to $dy$ and everything pops out nice. That's a little bit of a simplification of what's going on, but hopefully enough details to give you more of an idea of it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do you learn more about these intricacies in real analysis?

Comment: Real analysis doesn't usually cover line integrals. Your first one or two real analysis courses will teach you your single variable calculus, but made rigorously. Real analysis will cover rigorous construction of $\mathbb{N,Z,R}$, derivatives, integrals, sequences and series, etc. All single variable stuff you learned will be made rigorous, plus many new concepts. These are functions of several variables, which the analysis of them has several different names. Some call it Multivariable Analysis, but at that point you're teetering on the edge of Differential Topology or something related.

Comment: A line integral over a curve embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a special case of a more general concept. A curve is $1$ dimensional. This line integral you've done is an integral over a $1$D curve, or really isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ in a sense, embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Multivariable analysis deals with the rigorous integration  of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Theres much more happening that you will find. But this is the general idea. Think of a line integral as a $1$D "surface" embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Multivariable analysis will deal with general manifolds and integration

Comment: Thanks a lot. What would you say are the prerequisites for taking up topology and multivariable analysis? Do you have any textbooks you could recommend?

Comment: You need a solid background in single-variable analysis, probably a semester's worth. Specifically with regards to analysis on manifolds, the book that our university uses, as well as my favorite, is "Analysis on Manifolds" by Munkres. For general topology, "Topology without Tears" by Morris is always a good choice. It's not going to give you EVERYTHING, but the title kinda speaks for itself, haha. Munkres assumes that you have a solid background in linear algebra and at least a semester of single-variable analysis before his book. Munkres' first chapter deals with the analysis and linear....

Comment: algebra you'll need. There's PDFs of his book online. Skim the first chapter and see how much of it you can work out.

Answer (score 1):

Your path for line integral is the line segment from $(0, 1, 0)$ to $(1, 0, 1)$.

So the points on the line will be given by $\, c(t) = (0, 1, 0) + t(1-0, 0-1, 1-0) = (t, 1 - t, t)$.
$(0 \leq t \leq 1)$

$|c'(t)| = \sqrt{1^2 + (-1)^2 + 1^2} = \sqrt3$

So your line integral becomes $I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \Bigg(t^2 + 2 (1-t) - t\Bigg) \, |c'(t)| \, dt$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Certainly. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question, how do we know the parameter t varies on [0, 1]?

Comment: @CalebWilliamsUIC $t = 0 \,$ and $\, t = 1$ give you those points when you substitute.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems obvious now.

Comment: You are welcome!